# Brute Force Decryption issue

Tags: java, encryption, brute-force

Ok, so yesterday, I submitted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824821/password-guessing-program-problems) question about an issue with an extra credit assignment I'm working on. Since then, I think I've made a little progress, but now I'm running into a couple of new problems that I could use some help with.

As I mentioned in my last post, my assignment is to decrypt an encrypted file. The file was encrypted with the PBEWithSHA1AndDESede algorithm and we don't have the password. The password is a dictionary word with no special characters or numbers. Also, the file is encrypted using an unmodified version of the Crypt class, linked below.

The way I'm trying to handle it is with brute force by just testing thousands of words pulled at random from a dictionary.

Here's my new code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordGuess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();

        String curWord = "";

        try {
            File aFile = new File("english.txt");
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(aFile);

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                curWord = reader.next();

                if (curWord.length() == 5) {
                    words.add(curWord);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

        Random numGen = new Random();
        int count = 0;
        int maxTries = 10000;
        int tries = 0;
        File extraIn = new File("extracredit.enc");
        File extraOut = new File("extra_out.txt");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Crypt c = new Crypt(randomGenerator(words, numGen));
                System.out.println(randomGenerator(words, numGen));
                byte[] bytes = FileIO.read(extraIn);
                System.out.println("Attempt number: " + tries++);
                FileIO.write(extraOut, c.decrypt(bytes));
                System.out.println("Success!");
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not read/write file");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (++count == maxTries) {
                    try {
                        throw e;
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        System.out.println("Encryption error.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String randomGenerator(ArrayList<String> w, Random i) {
        return w.get(Math.abs(i.nextInt(w.size())));
    }
}
```

The code seems to run as intended, but when I go back and look through some of the results in the console, I'm seeing random "Success!" messages after incorrect password attempts. My question is why is the code able to keep running after the System.out.println("Success!"); line is able to run? I was under the impression that the code would terminate if the password was guessed correctly and the "Success!" message was displayed because it wouldn't have thrown the Exception.

Also, the code is still writing out a text file upon failed password guesses. Any ideas on why that might be are welcome!

Again, any helpful information at all is greatly appreciated! And here's the [Crypt](http://pastebin.com/2G7xyada) class for those of you interested in running the code yourself.

Comment: Could you please indent your code? It's hard to read as of right now...

Comment: mmmh.. Still not indented properly, I'll just do it ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to any sort of programming, so I'm still learning how to format things well.

Comment: You're probably using an IDE to write your code (Eclipse?). IDEs always provide auto-indenting features. In eclipse, use Ctrl+Maj+F. I'm spamming it all the time :D

Comment: Could you post the `Crypt` class? Is `c.decrypt()` throwing an exception on failure? What exception is it? You should probably catch this very exception, not the very general `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why is the code able to keep running after the
>   System.out.println("Success!"); line is able to run?

If `"Success!"` is printed, then it means you reached the end of the `try` block in your `while(true)` loop without any exception. **Since it's a `while(true)`, it keeps on going.**

You may add a `System.exit(0);` or `return;` after that `println`, if you want it to stop there.

### Other remarks

#### Algorithm

You're trying a bruteforce here, but using random words. This may end in a very long time, and is not guaranteed to try all the words (unless after waiting for an infinite amount of time).

Do something more natural, like trying all the words one by one (in order) instead of random words, this is bruteforce.

#### Printing errors on System.out

As a general rule, you should probably print your errors on the error stream instead of `stdout`. Do it using `System.err.println()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

But I agree, here decryption errors are not really errors in the proper meaning, so stdout is fine, but then these pieces of code should probably not be in a `catch` clause.

#### Try with a single throw

This is pointless, because the exception is always thrown.

```
try {
      throw e;
} catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println("Encryption error.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You can replace the while `try-catch` by what you put in the catch, this'll have the same effect:

```
System.out.println("Encryption error.");
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still having essentially the same problem. Including the `System.exit(0);` after the `println` just ends the program after the first incorrect guess that allows the `"Success!"` message to be displayed. I can't seem to figure out why the code is allowing the `"Success!"` message to be displayed after a random incorrect guess.

Comment: Take a look at the `continue` statement, instead of using exceptions here for decryption. That should help you achieve your goal. It basically skips the rest of the code for this loop turn, and goes to next lap directly.

Answer (score 0):

The program will continue looping after a success message is printed (while(true)).

Why must every attempt at decryption raise an error?